# vscode plugin change icon in problems window

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am making a vs code plugin for the output in problems pane at the bottom of the editor.

I get the message set by `diagnostics.push()`. But I want to change the icon that is displayed next to it. It's a cross in a red circle by default. Is there any way I can do it?

```js
diagnostics.push({
    severity: DiagnosticSeverity.Information,
    range: {
        start: { line: message.line, character: 0 },
        end: { line: message.line , character:  10 }
    },
    message: `${message.message}`,
    source: 'My source',
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The icon is controlled by the `severity` of the diagnostic:

- [image] `DiagnosticSeverity`.**`Error`**
- [image] `DiagnosticSeverity`.**`Warning`**
- [image] `DiagnosticSeverity`.**`Information`**
- [image] `DiagnosticSeverity`.**`Hint`**

I don't think extensions can currently contribute a different icon.